# MYSQL Error at restoring database: Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT

Tags: mysql, restore

For many times I have done successfully the same sequence for restoring the database commerce_db_622:

1. Go to the directory /usr/local/mysql/data and perform the command:

   ```
   sudo rm -rf COMMERCE_DB_622.
   ```

This drops the database COMMERCE_DB_622

2. Start the DB client :

   ```
    mysql –u root
   ```
3. Run the following script to create the database:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE COMMERCE_DB_622 /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
   ```
4. Move to the directory that stores the dump file COMMERCE_DB_622.sql and run the following command:

   `mysql -u root COMMERCE_DB_622 < COMMERCE_DB_622.sql`

This worked fine but suddenly today I am starting getting the error with the **valid already checked backup file**.

> ERROR 1813 (HY000) at line 25: Tablespace for table
>   '`commerce_db_622`.`batch_job_execution`' exists. Please DISCARD the
>   tablespace before IMPORT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the database using the following:
cd data; sudo rm -rf COMMERCE_DB_622;

However, the important thing is always in the beginning use the regular remove SQL:
DROP DATABASE COMMERCE_DB_622

If the "DROP DATABASE" SQL results in error then one can remove the data using the remove directory command.